# Html table not working on internet explorer

Tags: html, css, angular

My table works perfectly on chrome and firefox but not working on Internet Explorer. Any idea what causes it ? 
Could it be the problem about angular.js ? or just I.E renders tables differently ? 
Is there any way to fix it ?

```
<div class="dashboard-container">
  <div class="dashboard-container_subcontainer">
  <table *ngIf="user && user.therapists" class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First name</th>
      <th scope="col">Last name</th>
      <th scope="col">Email</th>
      <th scope="col">Country</th>
      <th scope="col">Status</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody *ngIf="sortedList">
    <tr *ngFor="let therapist of sortedList; let i = index" class="clickable" (click)="toggleRowColor(i); setTherapist(therapist)"  [ngClass]="{'border-green': i == selectedRow}">
      <th class="smallcolmn" scope="row">{{i+1}}</th>
      <td class="biggercolmn">{{therapist.firstName}}</td>
      <td class="biggercolmn">{{therapist.lastName}}</td>
      <td class="biggercolmn">{{therapist.email}}</td>
      <td class="biggercolmn">{{therapist.country}}</td>
      <td class="biggercolmn" [ngClass]="{'background-blue': therapist.status === TherapistStatus.REGISTERED, 'background-lightBlue': therapist.status === TherapistStatus.READY_FOR_TEST,
      'txt-blue': therapist.status === TherapistStatus.CERTIFIED_FOR_APP}">{{constantService.status[therapist.status]}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody *ngIf="!sortedList">
    <tr *ngFor="let therapist of therapistList; let i = index" class="clickable" (click)="toggleRowColor(i); setTherapist(therapist)"  [ngClass]="{'border-green': i == selectedRow}">
      <th class="smallcolmn" scope="row">{{i+1}}</th>
      <td class="biggercolmn">{{therapist.firstName}}</td>
      <td class="biggercolmn">{{therapist.lastName}}</td>
      <td class="biggercolmn">{{therapist.email}}</td>
      <td class="biggercolmn">{{therapist.country}}</td>
      <td class="biggercolmn" [ngClass]="{'background-blue': therapist.status === TherapistStatus.REGISTERED, 'background-lightBlue': therapist.status === TherapistStatus.READY_FOR_TEST,
      'txt-blue': therapist.status === TherapistStatus.CERTIFIED_FOR_APP}">{{constantService.status[therapist.status]}}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  </div>
  <app-info-container *ngIf="therapist && isOnline"  class="infoContainer" (isInfoBoxHidden)='resetSelectedTherapist()' [chosenTherapist] = "therapist"></app-info-container>
  <div class="noInternetConnection"*ngIf="!isOnline">No online connection available. Please reconnect.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please specify the IE version as well, and also the screenshot of the table, how its actually looking there

Comment: I.E 11 not working.. But i need also 7+. there is totally no table there. So screenshot wouldnt help. Its just empty where the table supposed to be

Comment: Can you prin your <tr> with IE 11 ? Did you go on your console to see if Angular say something ? Read this also https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-fix-your-angular-app-when-its-not-working-in-ie11-eb24cb6d9920

Comment: Try creating the table without the <thead> and <tbody> tags, if still doesn't work, just try without the *ngFor , I know it is required, but just to debug it.